# Animate rotation in Unity3d

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, transition

I'm working on a 2D game in Unity3D (using Orthello 2D).

Since I switched from Cocos2d and CoronaSDK, I'm wondering if there's a way of implementing the following behaviour for a sprite (or any Unity3D object) as it worked in Corona:

```
object = ...
transition.to ( object, { time = 1000, rotation = object.rotation + 100, onComplete = function () 
    // do something
end })
```

So a sprite rotates by 100 degrees over 1 second.

In my script attached to a sprite I can have a rotation in my `Update ()` function, but it's a bit different approach...

Comment: There are several interpolation utilities available for Unity, like iTween and GoKit. I think if you Google them you'll find examples/tutorials that do this sort of thing.  Unity also has a bunch of Lerp/Slerp functions on objects if you wanted to write your own interpolations. http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/30_search.html?q=Lerp

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll start by giving iTween a try.

Comment: iTween has a nice simple syntax, but supposedly GoKit performs better, so if you're writing something that's going to be doing tons of tweening on a mobile device, for example, you might need to switch at some point. If you search for "tween" in the Unity Asset Store you'll see some other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily in an Update function.

```
float timer = 0f;

void Update()
{
    if(timer <= 1)
    {
// Time.deltaTime*100 will make sure we are moving at a constant speed of 100 per second
        transform.Rotate(0f,0f,Time.deltaTime*100);
// Increment the timer so we know when to stop
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

If you need to do another 100 degrees rotation you will just have to reset the timer.

You can see different version of the Rotate function [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) and more information about the lifesaver `Time.deltaTime` value [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are several differnt ways of doing that. For example using a coroutine:

```
IEnumerator TweenRotation(Transform trans, Quaternion destRot, float speed, float threshold )
{
  float angleDist = Quaternion.Angle(trans.rotation, destRot);

  while (angleDist > threshold)
  {
    trans.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(trans.rotation, destRot, Time.deltaTime * speed);
    yield return null;

    float angleDist = Quaternion.Angle(trans.rotation, destRot);
  }
}
```